# Find Domain of Log Function

Tags: functions

Need help determining the Domain of $$\log_2\left(2x+3\right)=\log_2\left(3x+4\right)-\log_2\left(3x+2\right)$$

Do not know if I should simplify first to get the domain, or to get the domain from the set logs that are in place?

Comment: Did you mean to have a log within the log (left-hand side), or is that a typo?

Comment: That was someones edit, I just meant one log on the left hand side.

Comment: I corrected it; is the question ok like this?

Comment: That is the original equation that I meant to input. I fixed it now so that the log function (3x+2) is subtracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an equation, and you can solve it. First of all we need to understand the single domains. That is easy. I will use the writing $\lg$ for the log base $2$.

$$\lg(2x+3)$$

This function exists iff $2x+3 >0$ hence $\boxed{x > -\frac{3}{2}}$.

$$\lg(3x+4)$$

This function exists if $3x+4 >0$ hence $\boxed{x > -\frac{4}{3}}$

$$\lg(3x+2)$$

This function exists if $3x+2 >0$ hence $\boxed{x >-\frac{2}{3}}$

Finally you can write th equation

$$\lg(2x+3) = \lg\left[(3x+4)/(3x+2)\right]$$

Where I used the well known property of the sum of log.

So now you can exponentiate in base $2$:

$$2x+3 = \frac{3x+4}{3x+2}$$

$$(2x+3)(3x+2) = 3x+4$$

$$6x^2 + 13x + 6 = 3x + 4$$

$$6x^2 + 10x + 2 = 0$$

Now you can solve it as a normal second degree equation

$$x = \frac{-10\pm\sqrt{100 - 48}}{12}$$

And check for the solutions, that don't have to be in contrast with the previous assumptions (necessarily).

Answer (score -1):

I see an equation, not (just) a function?

In any case: $\log_a x$ (for a positive base $a$, different from $1$) is only defined for $x>0$. So for any logarithm appearing in your equation, the argument of the logarithm has to be strictly positive.

E.g. for $\log_2(3x+2)$ you need $3x+2>0 \Leftrightarrow x > -\tfrac{2}{3}$.

For all logarithms to be defined, you'll want the intersection of the 'domains' (sets where the different logarithms are defined), *before simplifying* (see below).

---

Notice that
$$\log x + \log x$$
is defined only for $x>0$ while (use $\log a + \log b = \log (ab)$)
$$\log \left( x^2 \right)$$
is defined for all $x\ne0$.

Comment: So the domain for the whole equation would be equal to x>-4/3, x>-2/3, x>-3/2?

Comment: I would reserve 'domain' for the context of functions; but your equation is well-defined for $x$-values satisfying $x>-4/3$ **and** $x>-2/3$ **and** $x>-3/2$; but you can simplify this to $x>-2/3$ (why?).

Comment: How could you say that $\log x^2$ is defined for all $x$??

$$\log(x^2) = 2\log(x)$$

!!

Comment: Not for all (please read what it says); for all non-zero $x$. The equality you write is only valid for $x>0$, more generally you have: $\log(x^2) = 2\log|x|$; or do you claim that $\log(x^2)$ is not defined for $x<0$...?

Comment: Downvote? I hope it's not because of my claim that $\log(x^2)$ is defined for all $x \ne 0$...

Comment: @StackTD For what concerns the down vote: I did not down voted you so I don't know who was.

Comment: So the domain could be simplified to x>-2/3 why?

Comment: @FourierTransform: alright thanks; I thought it could've come with your comment. Note though that properties such as $2\log x = \log x^2$ don't show / prove that $\log x^2$ would not exist for $x<0$, the equality just doesn't hold for some $x$-values (where one side exists, but the other doesn't).

Comment: @Revinous: If $x$ has to be larger than 3 values, then $x$ simply has to be larger than the largest of those 3 (and automatically satisfies the other conditions) - you see?

Comment: @StackTD Ok, thanks. This is only possible because of like bases? Right?

Comment: @Revinous No, watch out. You can only use most properties for log's in the same base, but the conditions on the argument (the domains) are independent of those bases.